# vs code not show output after i change the setting

Tags: json, settings, blank-line

in my vs code blank terminal show there is no path or I can't write anything
I reset all the setting of vs code then this problem arise
after reset Json setting is blank with this only {}
no file can run in vs code
please give the solution so
my vs code can run as it is new